# Unable to determine device. when i tray to load simulator in xcode 8.2.1

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode8.2

[![image show all window for simulator][The error i got when i launch simulator. i think accidentally i removed some of folder or directory from ~library/Developer folder. ]][i installed new xcode8.2.1 using latest Macox/Osx reboot system/simulator/xcode multiple  time]

Answer (score 0):

i Just Download new Xcode 8.2.1.xip extrect it ,than quit xcode and restart my mac mini it solved automatically.